# Simulation of a PR2 mobile robot

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody,

I  am trying to run a simulation of a PR2 mobile robot inside a building using Gazebo 1.4 running under Ubuntu 12.04.

First of all, I would like to ask you if it exists a world constructor like Gzbuilder 3D, as this is obsolete. As I have not found it until now, I have started to build it with gazebo’s builder, but I have noticed that when two walls join at an angle different from 0 or 180 degrees, the corners protrude. That is, they don’t align properly. Is there any easy way to fix it? Could this affect in any way to PR2 simulated sensors?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2001/simulation-of-a-pr2-mobile-robot/) by [rk7](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/275/rk7/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-28**:
if you mean the building editor, the corners are currently as they are now, the edges are not smoothed or rounded. As for effect on PR2 simulated sensors, it depends on what you want to do and what sensor you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

gzbuilder is very much an outdated. It has not been distributed with Gazebo for many years, and should be considered dead.

With Gazebo 1.5, you can create terrains using greyscale images. Take a look at `worlds/heightmap.world` for an example.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0